# Is it "louden your voice" or "make your voice louder"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Which of these are the correct way of saying it:

- "louden your voice" 
  or
- "make your voice louder"?

Or are both acceptable? Thanks :)

Comment: Both are _grammatical_; that is, both adhere to the rules of how English syntax and morphology work. You wouldn’t be very likely to hear native English speakers say either, though—the most common phrase used for this is ***“speak up”*** (or, if it’s not someone who’s currently speaking, for example if it’s someone singing, ***“louder (please)”*** on its own does the trick).

Comment: *Louden* is listed [in the dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/loud?q=louden#loud__15). Does that answer the question? [It would be understood, but I'd use "raise your voice", though]

Comment: As Janus says, both are exactly as grammatical as they are unidiomatic. If your intention is to blow your cover as a commie mutant traitor spy, use either. If it isn't, use neither.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Sounds  a good enough reason to start using them. I shall bear that in mind.

Comment: Say "I can't hear you", then he/she will raise his/her voice. "Speak up" might sound a bit rude to some people. I guess "I can't hear you" is the most polite one and widely used. Hope it helps.

Comment: @AndrewLeach If one can *quieten* one's voice why not *louden* it?

Comment: @WS2 of course you can, but it's not normally what's said (either Janus' "speak up" or my "raise your voice" would be customary, depending on context). I don't think I've ever actually heard *louden* used about voices, precisely because there are other idiomatic phrases which are preferred -- which was Reg's point.

Comment: Normally it would be "Speak up" or "Speak louder, please".  Or simply "Louder!", when a speaker is trying to address an audience.

Answer (score 1):

You say 'raise' or 'lower' your voice for 'louden' or 'quieten'. As in "Don't you you raise your voice to me!" meaning "Do not increase the volume of your voice when talking to me". This causes singing teachers some distress, as 'raise' and 'lower' can also refer to pitch.